# прошу объяснить, как так получилось?

Tags: php

```php
$m = date('m');

function p($m){
    $m0 = $m % 10;


    if($m >= 5 && $m <=20 ){
        $res = 'минут';
    }
    else if($m0 == 1){
         $res = 'минута';
    }
    else if($m0 >= 2 && $m0 <= 4 ){
        $res  = 'минуты';
    }
    else{
        $res = 'минут';
    }
    return $res;
}

echo $m . p($m);

?>
```

1. $m = date('i'); // с помощью этой функции вызывается показ минут;
2. $m % 10; // с помощью этой записи мы отсекаем первое число, будет от 0 до 9; например  19/10 = 9;

тогда откуда $m0 = $m % 10 PHP выдаст двухзначное число?

например подставим сюда $m0 = $m % 10 цифры; 9 = 19/10;

Comment: Anton Kucenko  я знаю что % это остаток от деления. Например 5/4 = 1 - это остаток от деления; в переменную $m подставляем любое 2-ое число, например 5 = 15 % 10; останется 5 (всегда число от 0 до 9), а тут $m0 = $m % 10 будет 2-ое число почему ? в переменной  $m0  будет 20 например, если $m % 10 будет всегда число от 0 до 9 ?

Comment: Как вы запускаете этот код ? Я не могу воспроизвести вашу проблему

Comment: Ivan Ignatiev - MSFT сейчас скину код

Comment: Ivan Ignatiev - MSFT скинул

Comment: в моих тестах от 0 до 100, ваш код всегда выдает однозначное число в $m0

Comment: а откуда предположение, что в `$m0` двузначное число?

Comment: Grundy  если вывести  с помощью echo даст 2 число;

Comment: @xes http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8c774cf6f391886f40bd4546b0388275047f09b все время 1 знак

Comment: а ты точно выводил `$m0`? Приведи пример входного параметра, и пример вывода

Comment: Grundy в моем коде выдает 2 число

Comment: @ Grundy  я код показал, там 2-ое число выходит почему ?

Comment: что значит _2-ое число_? Приведи это число. В приведенном коде $m0 нигде не выводится. Выводится `$m`

Comment: обновил страницу в моем коде выдало 38минут

Comment: Grundy нашел ошибку, просто разные переменные, вот и выводит на экран 2 число :)))

Comment: так об этом тебе в комментариях несколько раз уже писали.

Comment: Grundy сорри не догнал